# Writing to a .json file

Tags: json, append

I am currently trying to write 2 pieces of user inputted code to a .json file without clearing the existing data. I believe it is a problem with the logins.append as it says there is no such thing. What would i have to use?

I have been searching around trying to find different suffixes to the logins.

```
def i():
    path_to_json = "./logins.json"
    with open("logins.json", "r") as content:
        logins = json.load(content)


    with open('logins.json', 'a') as outfile:
        username = str(input('New Username: '))
        password = str(input('New Password: '))
        logins.append({username:password})
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    i()
  File "N:\NEA Computing\NEA code.py", line 188, in i
    logins.append({username: password})
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I am expecting it to add data to the .json file without deleting the other data however i am getting an error and nothing is being written to the .json file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the file with 'w' option

```
def i():
        path_to_json = "./logins.json"
        with open("logins.json", "w") as content:
            logins = json.load(content)


        with open('logins.json', 'a') as outfile:
            username = str(input('New Username: '))
            password = str(input('New Password: '))
            logins.append({username:password})
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because the 'w' would cause the .json to wipe all the contents of the file however i do not want it to do that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a misunderstanding of the question, but what is happening, as far as I can see, is that you use json.load, which seems to load an **object literal** like `{key1: value1, key2: value2,...}` and not an **array literal** like `[value1, value2, ...]`. Python converts the first one into a python dict, and a dictionary has no append function, only an array / a list has. You get your error and execution halts. When you have the content of logins.json as object `{...}`, it doesn't work for me but as array/list `[...]` it works